# Limits with exponents

Tags: limits, exponential-function

Novice asking for help and a bit of explanation on finding the limit of a function as $x$ gets closer to 0.

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{e^{5x} - e^{x}}{\arcsin x + x^{3}}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$=4\lim_{x\to0}e^x\dfrac{e^{4x}-1}{4x}\cdot\dfrac1{\dfrac{\arcsin x+x^3}x}=\text{?}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since the numerator and denominator both approach $0,$ L'Hopital's rule works, unless it doesn't (sometimes you have to try it and see in each case).

$$
\lim_{x\to0} \frac{e^{5x} - e^x}{\arcsin x + x^3} = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{5e^{5x} - e^x}{\frac 1 {\sqrt{1-x^2}} + 3x^2}
$$
This last limit is the limit of a function that is continuous at $0,$ so you can just plug in $0.$ You get $4.$

Comment: The first thing I thought of when looking at this is that $e^{5x} = 1 + 5x + \text{higher-degree terms}$ and $e^x = 1 + x + \text{higher-degree terms}$ and $\arcsin x = x + \text{higher-degree terms}.$ So you have $$ \frac{4x + \text{higher-degree terms}}{x + \text{higher-degree terms}} \to 4 \text{ as }x \to 0. $$